# Localization of ASP.NET login control

Tags: asp.net, localization

I am trying to localize standart ASP.NET login control. When I change page culture I want label 'password' to be automatically translated. I know how to work with resources in ASP.NET but I do not want to make localization myself, I am sure that microsoft has already translated all captions and error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this instruction :

1. [Download and install the German language pack for .NET 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=de&FamilyID=39C8B63B-F64B-4B68-A774-B64ED0C32AE7)
2. In the webform's source, add `UICulture="auto"` in the `<%@ Page` directive, for example: `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" UICulture="auto" %>`
3. View this page in browser, change your browser's preferred language to
   German, Then you should see the login control displayed in German language.

If you installed other language packs, users browsing your web site can set
their preferred language and your web page will display in the language if
its installed.

Hope this help you.

[Source](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/15_2006_8_0_0_805370/Localization-of-the-ASP-NET-login-control.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried to install .NET 3.5 sp1 language pack but it failed to install due to compatibility issues.
.NET 2.0 language pack also failed to install because 'this product is already installed'.

Answer (score 1):

You can try on your login control to press the tooltip and then click layout template.

Here you will get your control just like this :

```
<asp:Login ID="loginForm" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="442px">
                            <LayoutTemplate>
                                <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style3">
                                            <table cellpadding="0" style="height:200px;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                                        &nbsp;</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                ...etc
```

You will find your controls as the user name label :

```
<asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" Text="<%$Resources:YourResourcefile,Key%>"></asp:Label>
```

and you can localize what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't or don't want to install the language pack, you can take control of the texts displayed by the `Login` control, using the `UserNameLabelText, PasswordLabelText and LoginButtonText` properties. Set them to your own resources, for example:

```
UserNameLabelText="<%$ Resources:resxfilename, m_lblUsername %>"
```